# Analysis Services: How to show the original parameters of Pivot Table Excel after computing filter?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, ssas, cube

When connecting to AnalysisService / Cube with Excel, I have a PivotTable in a Excel Tab.

Here it is.

[image: First_Step_Pivot_Table]

And the PivotTable settings is in the Sheet1
[image: Excel Sheet]

THEN I do **double-click** in the corresponding cell where excel tells me "DOUBLE CLICK"

[image]

What I am trying to say is that I can perform many Pivot Table and filters, and excel creates, for every settings, a NEW TAB after I perform also the Double-click.

[image: Double Click]
Ok.

But then, how I recall again the original settings for each Excel TAB ?

What is the way to show the originals parameters for every Tab, in Excel, that were used to compute and search or filter some results ?

Maybe there is not a way.

**Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO**

**Version 2111 Build 16.0.14701.20278) 64-bit**

The results in a Excel TAB (Just an example) after doing the double-click to compute the fields putted in the PivotTable

[image: Results]

The question is. How, from the results, I can return back to the original settings that originated the table data ? If I don't remember the original parameters that I've put, how I see them again, FOR EVERY TAB ?

If it's not clear, please let me know in the comments
Thanks !

Comment: What version of Excel? I thought the filters showed up on top of the drill through report?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @GregGalloway  ! (I've put the Excel version in the post.)    Yes, there are the filters, yes, in the column, but I want to see again the original PivotTable fields from the screenshot 1, the Ones that originated the data. Thumbs up for the question ? :D

Comment: Which cell are you double clicking to drillthrough? Can you screenshot your PivotTable?

Comment: @GregGalloway I double Click the First Cell, where it says: Double Click. From the PivotTable I can run different queries and a new TAB in the Excel is created. Then the PivotTable in the Sheet1 only shows the last one, but what about all the other queries already performed ? I try to explain better the post.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of what “the first cell” means? The filters should display above the drillthrough table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once the query is submitted, there's noway to see the original filter.